# Coming back Google Play Services

Tags: samsung, google-play-services, services

I have Samsung Galaxy A50 which is my professional smartphone, I use it for work and it is funded by my company. It has some professional software installed in Knox like encrypted e-mail etc.

I am observing problem with Google Play services app/service. I have message coming from time to time saying (translated):

```
Device Health Services
Enable Google Play Services
Device Health Services app won't work if you do not enable Google Play Services
```

I've tried to turn off this message by disabling notifications from three apps:

1. Google Play Service
2. Device Health Services
3. FAMOC

This didn't helped. Still I get the same message between few minutes to few hours.

When I click this message I get possibility to enable or stop Google Play Services but the enable button does not work - it does nothing or sometimes is disabled. From this screen it is obvious that the app is stopped. However when going to Settings menu and below I get info that the app is enabled and working.

Stopping the app also does nearly nothing. Clearing data and/or cache does not help. Downgrade of this app is not possible. Deactivation also is not possible.

The app version is 19.2.75 (100400-269183835). It is the newest as I have other phone and the version on it is the same.

The app does not make any problems, there are no errors.

How can I get rid off this message coming from time to time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution.

When you block notifications for all 3 apps it is not enough.

You need to hold this specific notification longer and use options there.

Problem solved!